# Efecto hover para cada elemento de un array en Angular

Tags: array, angular, hover, componentes, card

¿Como puedo hacer para que cada elemento de una array tengo un efecto hover individual si estoy usando un ngFor para listarlos?
Tengo lo siguiente.
archivo TS.

```
       miEducacion:any=[
      {
      "logoInstituto":"logo-Instituto",
      "nombreInstituto":"Next U",
      "descripcionInstituto":"Diplomatura Dev Web."
      },
      {
       "logoInstituto":"logo-Instituto",
       "nombreInstituto":"Oracle",
       "descripcionInstituto":"Base de datos"
      }
```

Esto lo paso a un ngFor. Lo hice como si fueran tarjetas El resultado es que tengo 2 tarjetas con los datos.

```
       <div class="container ">
         <div class="row educacion-anuncio">
          <div class="col">
        <h1>Educacion <span><button class="agregarInfo">Agregar Experiencia</button></span> </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-educacion">
       <div class="col-md-5 contenedor-educacion" *ngFor="let educacion of miEducacion" >
         <div class="row ">
           <div class="col-4 logoEducacion">
            {{educacion.logoInstituto}}
           </div>     
         <div class="col-8 textoEducacion">
            <h3>{{educacion.nombreInstituto}}</h3>
            <p>{{educacion.descripcionInstituto}}</p>            
            <span> <fa-icon [icon]="faTrash"></fa-icon></span>
            <span> <fa-icon [icon]="faPen"></fa-icon></span>
          </div>        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

mi intencion es que cuando haga un hover a cada tarjeta que contiene los datos del array, me haga un efecto. Esto es lo que tengo en css.

```
  .container{
     background-color: #EA6309;
  }
 .educacion-anuncio{
    background-image: url(../../../assets/sun-tornado.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color:white;   
  }
  .contenedor-educacion{
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    position: relative;  
    background-color: aliceblue;  
    box-shadow: 7px 9px 18px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   }

  .textoEducacion{
    padding: 20px;
   }

  .textoEducacion span{
     margin:0px 5px;
     padding:10px;
     font-size:15px;
     border: 1px solid #231D16;
     border-radius:25%;
    }
 .row-educacion{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
   }
  .logoEducacion{
   background-color: #F8932D;
   clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
  .agregarInfo{
    float:right;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:0px 5px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #231D16;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
```

Lo intente dandole
.row-educacion:hover{
hace algo
}

Pero esto me afecta a los 2 elementos que tengo y supongo que pues sea por el ngFor.
Saludos desde ya.

[image: Rederizado]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con

```
.contenedor-educacion:hover{
}
```

Puesto que esa clase es la que se repite en cada contenedor.

Cuando usas  .row-educacion:hover se aplica a todo lo que este dentro.

Comment: Gracias Fernando. Ya me salio. Tal cual me dijiste. Ahora tengo etro problema relacionado con esto mismo. EL hover me funciona individualmente. ahora quiero que cada elemento del array responda a un evento click. este evento click lo que hace es cambiarme el estado de una variable booleana, que luego la uso para un ngClass. Esta clase lo que cambia es unas propiedades que hace que div se muestre. pasa que al hacer click me toma hace esta accion a todos los elementos del array.